# How do you use the "break" option when making histograms?

Tags: r

I am confused as to how the breaks argument works in the "hist()" function.

I have created a historgram of a rnorm(200, 0, 1). The default parameters make it look a certain way when writing hist(x).

I then wanted to change the breakpoints by doing hist(x, breaks=5). I end up with 6 breakpoints (or is it 8? I don't know if you count the outer breaks), and 7 bins. To make matters even more confusing, when I change the argument to break = 6 or 7 or even 8, the histogram doesn't change at all!

I'm new to R and to statistics in general; is there anyone that understands how all of this works? Certain sources say that, say I have breaks = n, I should be getting n + 1 bins. Other sources say that the way the algorithm works, I cannot really choose how many bins or breaks I have.

Which is true? Can anyone shed some light on this topic?

The documentation provided by RStudio itself doesn't help, as it seems to say that the breaks option can mean a variety of things (most of which I don't understand as, again, I am new to this.)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is all in R; I should have mentioned that in the title.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post will provide the answer you are looking for: https://www.r-bloggers.com/basics-of-histograms/.

The article mentions that "The bins don’t correspond to exactly the number (of bins) you put in, because of the way R runs its algorithm to break up the data but it gives you generally what you want. If you want more control over exactly the breakpoints between bins, you can be more precise with the breaks() option and give it a vector of breakpoints, like this:

hist(BMI, breaks=c(17,20,23,26,29,32), main=”Breaks is vector of breakpoints”)

This dictates exactly the start and end point of each bin.  Of course, you could give the breaks vector as a sequence like this to cut down on the messiness of the code:

hist(BMI, breaks=seq(17,32,by=3), main=”Breaks is vector of breakpoints”)"

Behind the scenes, R can use one of three algorithms when choosing the breaks for a histogram: Sturges, Scott or Freedman-Diaconis. According to the help file for hist:

"The default for breaks is "Sturges": see nclass.Sturges. Other names for which algorithms are supplied are "Scott" and "FD" / "Freedman-Diaconis" (with corresponding functions nclass.scott and nclass.FD). Case is ignored and partial matching is used. Alternatively, a function can be supplied which will compute the intended number of breaks or the actual breakpoints as a function of x."

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the source I was speaking of when I wrote "Other sources say that the way the algorithm works, I cannot really choose how many bins or breaks I have."

That is the thing I don't understand; if the number of breaks I am asking for doesn't correspond to the number of breaks it gives me, then what does it correspond to? How does it determine the number of breaks it  shows?

Comment: The take away message of the blog post is that if you want to control exactly the number of bins (rather than let R come up with a number of bins that is "close" to what you want), you have to specify the start and end point of each bin.

Comment: The function truehist fom the MASS package often gives better results than the hist function in terms of the appearance of a histogram, so you can investigate it further for your needs.